# Are winapi handles global?

Tags: winapi

A very simple question, if i create a `HANDLE` in app1.exe and it gets value `0x01` is that value globally unique ?

Or is it possible that when some other process creates a `HANDLE` that also has value `0x01`.

If they are not unique what other construct can i use to get a unique id compatible with handles (such that it will be impossible or highly unlikely that a `HANDLE` with that id is created anywhere else).

Comment: http://www.windows-api.com/microsoft/Win32-Kernel/31543684/wrappinghooking-api-how-to-handle-closehandle.aspx related reading ;)

Comment: You have asked two questions in one. I answered one about whether `HANDLE` unique, but the answer to the other depends on what do you need an unique id for.

Comment: for spoofing CreateFileW ReadFile of another process (also other things) using hooks.

Comment: @SteveValliere the other question talks about HWND which are a different thing

Comment: Sorry, been at this too long.  When I started programming for Windows, HWND was a special type of handle.  Now there is a HANDLE type for some handles and a DECLARE_HANDLE type that is used for HWND and a few other things.  Apparently a handle is not always a handle any more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The important thing to understand is that handles are not objects. Handles are pointers (or indexes) to per-process object table. To answer your question, HANDLES are not globally unique, but they are scoped to only make sense inside a particular process.

For any kernel object to be able to be accessible from other process, you have to [DuplicateHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724251.aspx).

Another way to share objects across processes is to call [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with *bInheritHandles* set to *true*.

Comment: inherithandles needs one process to create another.. no can do ;P

Answer (score 3):

They are not unique. `HANDLE` values are local to the current process. Same value may be invalid handle or refer to a different object in another process. An exception to this rule are handles inherited from parent process.

The only way to have unique id without a centralized registry is to use `GUID`. But they are not compatible with HANDLE, they are 128-bit while handles are 32 or 64-bit.

Answer (score 2):

Use [DuplicateHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724251%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to pass handles between processes.